# Reshape python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have dataframe like this.

| description |
| --- |
| Brian |
| No.22 |
| Tel:+00123456789 |
| email:brain@email.com |
|  |
| Sandra |
| No:43 |
| Tel:+00312456789 |
|  |
| Michel |
| No:593 |
|  |
| Kent |
| No:13 |
| Engineer |
| Tel:04512367890 |
| email:kent@yahoo.com |

and I want it like this.

| name | address | designation | telephone | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brian | No:22 | null | Tel:+00123456789 | email:brain@email.com |
| Sandra | No:43 | null | Tel:+00312456789 | null |
| Michel | No:593 | null | null | null |
| Kent | No:13 | Engineer | Tel:04512367890 | email:kent@yahoo.com |

How to do this in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.where` to label each row then `pivot` your dataframe.

**Step 1.**

```
condlist = [df['description'].shift(fill_value='').eq(''),
            df['description'].str.contains('^No[:.]'),
            df['description'].str.startswith('Tel:'),
            df['description'].str.startswith('email:')]
choicelist = ['name', 'address', 'telephone', 'email']
df['column'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='designation')
print(df)

# Output:
              description       column
0                   Brian         name
1                   No.22      address
2        Tel:+00123456789    telephone
3   email:brain@email.com        email
4                          designation
5                  Sandra         name
6                   No:43      address
7        Tel:+00312456789    telephone
8                          designation
9                  Michel         name
10                 No:593      address
11                         designation
12                   Kent         name
13                  No:13      address
14               Engineer  designation
15        Tel:04512367890    telephone
16   email:kent@yahoo.com        email
```

**Step 2.** Now remove empty rows and create an index to allow the pivot:

```
df = df[df['description'].ne('')].assign(index=df['column'].eq('name').cumsum())
print(df)

# Output:
              description       column  index
0                   Brian         name      1
1                   No.22      address      1
2        Tel:+00123456789    telephone      1
3   email:brain@email.com        email      1
5                  Sandra         name      2
6                   No:43      address      2
7        Tel:+00312456789    telephone      2
9                  Michel         name      3
10                 No:593      address      3
12                   Kent         name      4
13                  No:13      address      4
14               Engineer  designation      4
15        Tel:04512367890    telephone      4
16   email:kent@yahoo.com        email      4
```

**Step 3.** Pivot your dataframe:

```
cols = ['name', 'address', 'designation', 'telephone', 'email']
out = df.pivot('index', 'column', 'description')[cols] \
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print(out)

# Output:
     name address designation         telephone                  email
1   Brian   No.22         NaN  Tel:+00123456789  email:brain@email.com
2  Sandra   No:43         NaN  Tel:+00312456789                    NaN
3  Michel  No:593         NaN               NaN                    NaN
4    Kent   No:13    Engineer   Tel:04512367890   email:kent@yahoo.com
```

**Edit**

> There is an error at final step" ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" how can I overcome this.

There is no magic to solve this problem because your data are mess. The `designation` label is the fallback if the row was not tagged to `name`, `address`, `telephone` and `email`. So there is a great chance, you have multiple rows labelled `designation` for a same person.

At then end of this step, check if you have duplicates (person/label -> index/column) with this command:

```
df.value_counts(['index', 'column']).loc[lambda x: x > 1]
```

Probably (and I hope for you), the output should indicate only `designation` label under `column` column unless one person can have multiple `telephone` or `email`. Now you can adjust the `condlist` to catch a maximum of pattern. I don't know anything about your data so I can't help you much.

Comment: Corralien, Thank you very much and it is a great help. Your steps are very clear. But when I apply your steps to actual, There is an error at final step" ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"  how can I overcome this.. Please help me..

Comment: The problem with your data is everything has not a label get the default label `designation` because we don't recognize any pattern to label the entry. So if for a group (index), you have many labels (column), `pivot` will raise an exception because it don't know how to process the duplicate cell (index/column).

Comment: Is it ok to drop duplicate index and how. Thanks

Comment: Try: `out = df.drop_duplicates(['index', 'column']).pivot('index', 'column', 'description')[cols].rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)`

Comment: As you instructed, I drop the duplicates and it worked..Thank you very much..